# How to archive files older than x days where the date is in the filename

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of files that has a date in them

Example:

```
Name_2019-07-06.xls
Name_2019-08-07.csv
...
Name_2019-09-01.xlsx
```

I need to archive only files that have a date older than 31 from today.

I can list all the files that are in a directory using the code below

```
FILES=/Users/Desktop/testArchive/*

for file in $FILES
do
    echo $(basename $file)

done
```

I expect to have a new folder which would have the files older than 31 days in their filename

Comment: Can you give more examples? Does the files have no extension? Please don't post images, copy them as text into your post.

Comment: None of your examples are older than 31 days.

Comment: The files will have .xls / .csv / .xlsx extentions.
I have made files that are older than 31 days, I just need to come up with the script so that the files would be automatically placed in a new folder named 'archived'.

Comment: @KamilCuk I cant add images, need more reputation points at the moment. I have updated the description of the problem by adding extensions and updating filenames.

Comment: Is `Name_` a placeholder or do all files really start with `Name_`?

Comment: All file names will start with a prefix of 'Name_' and will follow up with a date, at the moment format has only YYYY-MM-DD, in the future, it may be YYYY-MM-DD:HH:MM:SS

Comment: @Cyrus, the logic that I am thinking of consists of:

Reading the file name, getting the part where it describes the date, comparing the date with now and moving the file to another folder if the date is older than 31 days from now.

Comment: Remove the link to image and post the filenames as text. With "don't post images" I meant: don't use any graphic form to represent textual data.

Answer (score 0):

I've appened a little snippet which extracts the date. It can be simplified but I think it's sufficient to demonstrate my way.

Starting with your loop I split the Name in some parts.

1. The name

```sh
b_file=$(basename $file)
```

2. Get the current file extension

```sh
file_ext="${b_file##*.}"
```

3. Replace the Characters not needed: *`${parameter/pattern/string}`* and *`${parameter%pattern}`*

```sh
# Get the characters behind 'Name_'
file_date=${b_file/Name_/}          
# Remove the file Extension
file_date=${file_date%.${file_ext}}
```

---

This is just a quick approach. `cur_date` stores the current date, it can be [formatted](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/) to match your needs (e.g date before 31 days).

In this case you just need to compare both strings.

So this is the whole snippet. Whenever a filename matches the current date, **[ .. matched ... ]** will be printed.

```sh
# To compare the date, change this to your date
cur_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)  

for file in $FILES
do
  # Store the Filename
  b_file=$(basename "$file")
  # Get the current file extension
  file_ext="${b_file##*.}"  

  # Remove the characters not needed
  # Get the characters behind 'Name_'
  file_date=${b_file/Name_/}    
  # Remove the file Extension       
  file_date=${file_date%.${file_ext}}   

  # Compare the dates
  if [ "$file_date" == "$cur_date" ]; then
    echo "The date of $b_file is $file_date. Current date matched: $cur_date" 
  else
    echo "The date of $b_file is $file_date. Current date: $cur_date"
  fi        
done
```

Example Output:

```
The date of Name_2019-07-06.xls is 2019-07-06. Current date: 2019-08-17
The date of Name_2019-08-07.csv is 2019-08-07. Current date: 2019-08-17
The date of Name_2019-08-17.xlsx is 2019-08-17. Current date matched: 2019-08-17
```